# Как открывать приложение при переходе на ссылку Android

Tags: java, android

Например, на сайте есть спец ссылки `aliexpress://product/desc?productId=32309744542` при переходе по которым открывается приложение AliExpress. Если мне нужно добавить GET параметр, например, `aliexpress://?param=32309744542` он должен быть передан в ссылку, так: `http://m.aliexpress.com?param=32309744542` (в обычном браузере). В приложении невозможно просмотреть ссылку поэтому я хочу узнать, будет ли это работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На андроиде схема такая:

1. В манифесте для нужной активити добавляется `IntentFilter`, в коем указывается на нажатия на какие ссылки нужно реагировать.
2. В этой активити, уже в коде через `Intent` вытаскивается ссылка, коей запущено приложение. Ссылка разбирается на части и выстраивается логика её обработки.

В манифесте примерно так (сначала идёт пример обычных ссылок на сайт, потом типа такой как вы в вопросе написали):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="site.org"
        android:pathPrefix="/something"
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data
        android:host="*.site.org"
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data
        android:host="www.site.org"
        android:pathPrefix="/something"
        android:scheme="http" />
   <data
        android:scheme="aliexpress" />
</intent-filter>
```

В активити получаем ссылку так:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
Log.d("ЛОГ", "Uri data: " + data);
```